# IE8 Cannot support media queries

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

I used the link tag to call the css using media queries but ie8 does not support media query, ie8+ support for the same media query.

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (min-width: 1200px)" href="something.css" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out:

https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond

The respond.js polyfill adds media queries support for ie. It loads stylesheets dynamically via silent ajax calls.